# Weird behavior of React UseEffect with window click eventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, use-effect

I'm trying to implement a simple window Click counter. It needs to count clicks on the entire page, not in a single element with like `<div onClick={() => handleClick()}></div>`.

I have tried many variations of this code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

function Test() {
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    try {
      setClicks(() => clicks + 1);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(clicks);
  }, [clicks]);

  useEffect(() => {
    $(window).on('click', handleClick);
    return () => {
      $(window).off('click', handleClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (<div>{clicks}</div>);
}

export default Test;
```

The first `useEffect` just logs the `click` state variable every time it changes, so I can see what is happening. The second one adds the event listener and removes it on component unmount.
The problem is that it works just fine for the first click. The first `useEffect` logs `1` and the value inside the `<div>` changes to `1`. But nothing else happens if I keep clicking. Is this approach wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a classical [stale closure](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function) problem. Use this instead:

```
  setClicks((clicks) => clicks+ 1);
```

The way you had it, your `clicks` would always refer to the value from the first render; it never got updated because you run your `useEffect` only once.

Comment: Dang! that was simple. Thanks!